# Python, making a wheel file

Tags: python, git, dependencies, pip, python-wheel

I am trying to make wheel file and I want to add git repo in dependencies but I the following message appeared: `error in me-pkg setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Invalid requirement, parse error at "'+ssh://g'"`.

The question is; How can I put git repo in dependencies or make this wheel file depend on another wheel file 
setup.py :

```
import os
from setuptools import find_packages, setup



# allow setup.py to be run from any path
os.chdir(os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(__file__), os.pardir)))

setup(
    name='me-pkg',
    version='0.1',
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    license='BSD License',  # example license
    description='A simple Django app to conduct Web-based polls.',
    url='https://www.example.com/',
    author='xxxxx',
    author_email='xxxxxxx@gmail.com',
    classifiers=[
        'Environment :: Web Environment',
        'Framework :: Django',
        'Framework :: Django :: X.Y',  # replace "X.Y" as appropriate
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: BSD License',  # example license
        'Operating System :: OS Independent',
        'Programming Language :: Python',
        # Replace these appropriately if you are stuck on Python 2.
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5',
        'Topic :: Internet :: WWW/HTTP',
        'Topic :: Internet :: WWW/HTTP :: Dynamic Content',
    ],

    install_requires=['git+https://github.com/xxx/xxx.git/stable/1.10.x'],

)
```

note : **Dependency links not working**

Comment: down voted for what ?!!

Comment: Try following this small tutorial. I have no tried it, but it seems pretty OK to me. https://mike.zwobble.org/2013/05/adding-git-or-hg-or-svn-dependencies-in-setup-py/

Comment: @kelmi92 thank you so much. working fine now